# There was a better answer but mine got chosen as the correct one

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, asking-questions

I recently answered a question on Stack Overflow and although mine was selected as the accepted answer, I could clearly see that it isn't the best answer. How do I essentially compel the person that asked the question to choose another answer?

Comment: You needn't, you shouldn't. Accepting is their choice. Instead, **"upvote posts that you find useful"**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepting is another user's choice, not yours. You can't compel them to change it, just like you can't compel people to vote a certain way in any other regard. Answer acceptances are more of a personal indication of "this is the solution I went with," or "this was the most helpful answer I received." In other words, it's the author's opinion.

If you'd like, you can comment asking them to re-evaluate their decision, but that's the extent of what you can do.

Just upvote the other answer to indicate you found it useful -- that's what upvotes are for.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my post got down voted like three times while the other posts all had positive votes. That was what indicated to me that my answer sucked

Comment: Fundamentally, answer acceptances are a vote, and the OP can use that vote however they'd like to.

Comment: alright, I'll make sure to keep that in mind in the future